# VLAN Across Trunked CISCO 2960-S Switches

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst

[image: My experimental setup]

With reference to the above diagram: Is 10.124.124.141 supposed to be able to ping 10.124.124.161 if the setup is correct ? There is no router in-between, the idea is that the VLAN 215 spans two switches trunked together to make a single 48-port switch if you wish. I am however not getting this to work (the ping fails from either side).
The configuration for port 16 on switch 2 is:

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/16
switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,215
switchport mode trunk
!
```

The configuration for port 11 on switch 1 is:

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/11
switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,215
switchport mode trunk
spanning-tree portfast
!
```

The configuration for port 21 on both switch 1 and 2 is:

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/21
switchport mode trunk
srr-queue bandwidth share 1 30 35 5
priority-queue out
mls qos trust cos
macro description cisco-switch
auto qos trust
spanning-tree link-type point-to-point
!
```

and port 23 is configured the same as port 21.

Comment: Why are you running trunk ports towards your hosts? Normally one would use an access port.

Comment: @user56700 - multiple VLANs per adapter

Comment: So, it's something like ESXi or other type of system that supports tagging on the NIC directly?

Comment: @JesseP. no, both hosts Linux, the VLANs are for easier QoS differentiation between broad classes of access to them

Comment: But how are you tagging the traffic on the hosts so it knows which VLAN to use? In trunk mode, with no native VLAN defined on the switch ports, you need to do the tagging on the hosts to tell it to use VLAN 215.

Comment: @JesseP. VLAN tagging is correctly setup on the Linux hosts

Comment: @Waslap For troubleshooting, have you tried changing the ports to access mode, defining access VLAN 215, undoing your tagging on the Linux hosts, and testing to see if it works? Just to make sure you at least can get that working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to apologise with my hat in my hand. I have swopped around two network cables on the back-plane of the server. In my defense, there are 4 cables marked with roman numerals and my eyes aren't that good so the II and III got swopped around.

Comment: Please accept your answer so this doesn't keep coming up as unsolved.

Comment: It says I can only accept in 2 days

Comment: Oh. Okay. I guess mark it in 2 days.  :)